# Possible to give IntelliSense on specific type defined in third party library like express while writing node.js in vscode?

Tags: express, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

Let's say i am starting a new web app with `express`, and have vscode as my IDE for this nodejs project

Following code is working well with IntelliSense:

[image]

Once the handler is extracted, IntelliSense is gone:

[image]

I've tried [jsdoc](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSDoc-support-in-JavaScript):

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {express.Request} req 
 * @param {express.Response} res 
 */
function test(req, res) {
  req. // no luck
}
```

Is there any way to have IntelliSense supported in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of VS Code 1.20, this is a limitation when using `require` with JSDoc types (see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19476)]

Workaround is to use `import`:

```
import * as express from 'express'

/**
 * 
 * @param {express.Request} req 
 * @param {express.Response} res 
 */
function test(req, res) {
  req.
}
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14377 also tracks allowing you to specify module imports in jsdocs directly.